# Converting PostgreSQL GeoJSON data into feature services ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Online can read

Tags: postgis, arcgis-pro

I am having a difficult time converting transforming my GeoJSON data stored in PostgreSQL to feature services ArcGIS Pro can load. I have tried https://github.com/doneill/koop-provider-pg & https://github.com/koopjs/koop-cli with no success.